# Do electrolytic capacitors lose lifetime during soldering in reflow oven?

Tags: capacitor, soldering, temperature, electrolytic-capacitor, reflow

Electrolytic capacitors service time is based on maximum operating temperature, among other things. When they are inside an SMD soldering oven, the temperature increases to over 375°C. Most of the capacitors are rated at 105°C.

Although there is no electricity flowing  through the capacitor, will the increased heat reduce its lifetime?

Comment: The specified lifetime ought to be if you followed the solder recommendations from the manufacturer. If the manufacturer didn't specify temperatures for soldering, then it's a bad datasheet. Unfortunately the majority of datasheets for these _are_ bad datasheets... I just peeked into a random Panasonic one and it does at least state which characteristics the cap should have after reflow soldering (and cooling).

Comment: I believe that capacitors are damaged *less* when *unpowered* and hot, and *more* when *powered* and hot.

Comment: I think your 375 °C is excessive, reflow ovens should reach around 260 °C maximum during a lead free soldering profile.

Comment: Yes, today I checked. It doesn't reach that much high temperature.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it does degrade, but the capacitor specifications such as lifetime are given when the specific and allowable soldering conditions taken already into account, as you can't really use a capacitor without soldering it to PCB first.

So you will get the rated life time, if you do the soldering within rated temperature limits, within rated time limits, and within rated number of soldering cycles.